Why watch is not execute when history is change
<script setup>
import InputChat from '../components/InputChat.vue'
import Chat from '../components/Chat.vue'
import Layout from "@/components/Layout.vue";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar.vue";
import ChatVue from '@/components/Chat.vue';
import { ChatManager } from '../../lib/ChatManager';
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
const manager = new ChatManager()
const historys = ref(manager.historys)

watch( historys ,(newHistory)=>{
  console.log("Watch execute");
  console.log(newHistory)
  console.log(historys.value);
},{deep:true})
const handleSentMessage = (value)=>{
  console.log(value + "Parent receive yet");
  manager.sentChat(value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <Layout>
    <template #sidebar>
      <Sidebar />
    </template>
    <template #chat>
      <Chat :history="manager.history"/>
    </template>
    <template #input-chat>
      <InputChat @sent-message = "handleSentMessage"/>
    </template>
  </Layout>
</template>



export class ChatManager {
   

  constructor() {
    this.url = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL || 'http://localhost:11434/api'
    this.historys = [];
    
  }
  async sentChat(message){
    const messageTemplate = {
      request:{
        role:"user",
        content: ''
      },
      response:{
        role:'assistant',
        content:''
      }
    }
    
    try {
      messageTemplate.request.content = message

      
      this.historys.push(messageTemplate)
      const response = await fetch(`${this.url}/chat`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          model: "llama2",
          messages: [
            {
              role: "user",
              content: message
            }
          ],
          stream: false
        })
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
       this.historys[this.historys.length-1].response.content = data.message.content
       this.historys[this.historys.length-1].response.role = data.message.role
      return data;

  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}

}

When history is change why watch is not execute i want when history is change watch is execute but now when history is change watch is not execute please help me

I may be overlooking the obvious ... but ... manager.history what is that? I can see what manager.historys is ... but manager.history remains mysterious

maybe try to call watch like this watch(()=> historys.value

ChatManager refers non-reactive historys array that cannot be watched.
The class should either explicitly use reactive for the fields, or can be made reactive when instantiated:
const manager = reactive(new ChatManager())
const historys = toRef(manager, 'historys')

watch(historys, ...)

Reactive classes have several pitfalls that require to implement them in a restricted way that's compatible with Vue reactivity. None of them are applicable to ChatManager so far.

You can refer to the vue3 official documentation for the description and usage about 'Deep Watcher'.
Use 'reactive' instead of 'ref'

This is not answering anything

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
